# Sql Server Management Studio 2008 has suddenly become unresponsive

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm getting a very strange error when I try to launch SSMS from my taskbar. It seems to open in normal speed, but responds to any input with just a beep. CPU usage is 0% in Task Manager, and there is no [not responding] message.

It doesn't respond to a right-click & close all windows command from the taskbar, but "End Task" from task Manager does kill it.

When I launch from the command line and specify the server using the -S switch & use Windows Auth using -E it runs fine.

Comment: Eirik Toft is spot on, this was exactly my problem. Couldn't get "Alt-Space m" to work but didn't matter. I have two desktop monitors and the laptop screen running, and the 'Connect to Server' dialog box presents itself in the dead space off all three monitors. It works perfectly if I shut the laptop lid and go back to just two monitors. One think I found which is an improvement is going to Tools > Options > Environment + General and changing 'At startup' to: 'Open empty environment'. This opens SSMS without the auto dialog prompt. Trouble is it still launches off screen if I go to Connect > D

Comment: don't bother reporting it - closed as "won't fix" https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/755689/sql-server-management-studio-connect-to-server-popup-dialog

Comment: First of all please check the file which you are working on. Create new file and do working on that if you observe that everything is fine, its mean your first file size is bigger than Mbs or may be the file is corrupt.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This might be a very simplistic answer, but this happened to me because a dialog it was attempting to present was off of the desktop and/or hidden behind something else.

When it beeps like that, can you do the whole "Alt-Space   m" and move something into focus?

Comment: Thanks, that put me in right track. It was simply a dialog box that was opening off screen. I have a dual monitor setup so I launched it from the command line and moved the window to the main monitor and then shut down. When I launched from the taskbar again the "connect to server" dialing appeared in the normal position.

Answer (score 7):

The 'Connect to Server' window is off-screen.  If you use Alt+F4, it will close the dialogue but keep Management Studio open.  After this you can initiate a new dialogue through the menu and connect to the desired server.

After closing, the 'Connect to Server' window should appear inside of the main window the next time you start the program.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem today and none of the solutions here worked, since it was not the connection dialog, but a different one hiding.

I went to the task manager and right-clicked on the dialog and selected "Bring to Front".

I hope this helps others!

Answer (score 0):

This morning i have experienced the exact same unresponsive SSMS (No keystrokes function, have "End Task" via "Task Manager").

My environment is similar to those indicated above;
Surface Pro 3 w/ 2 additional monitors (total of three).

After killing SSMS, moving SSMS to monitor #1 before closing it works.
When I re-open SSMS the dialogue box properly appears on monitor #1.  I can then move SSMS to monitor #2 or #3.